# Load masonry.js from local machine throws error

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I am trying to load the masonry.js file from my local machine, but it doesn't work. Until now I came across with the CDN link of masonry, but as soon as I remove the CDN link the following error is thrown:

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).masonry is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (gallery:229)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

Code:

```
<script src="{{ asset(mix('js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js')) }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset(mix('js/masonry.pkgd.min.js')) }}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    // init Masonry
    var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
    });
    // layout Isotope after each image loads
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
      $grid.masonry();
    });
});
</script>
```

I checked a couples of times whether jquery is setup properly, it is. You can't see the jQuery file because it is in another view I am using blade templates. I don't know what it could be any more.

Comment: Have you checked your browser network tab, to see if you have any assets that are not loading?

Comment: In the browser network tab everything is loaded properly. I think it has something to do with my jquery, because of the error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).masonry is not a function. The strange thing is with the CDN link of masonry it works as expected.

Comment: Update if I put the whole js in script tags it works but if I load it through link locally no chance....

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole JS" - the Masonry plugin?

Comment: yo, masonry sry